# I staked ZRX through Metamask on OX Protocol and it was an account linked to my Exodus Wallet. now I can't link to my staking

Tags: metamask, import

ok connected metamask to stake ZRX on OX protocol.  imported OX keys from my exodus wallet to a new account in metamask. seemed to work for a bit then one day i tried to check on things and it wouldn't connect or log in to my imported account on metamask.  won't load tokens either.  you can see on etherscan the wallet
https://0x.org/zrx/account  this says loading gathering data for your wallet
metamask says connected but won't load any balances
etherscan shows all balances in exodus
also shows address is on 2 other chains. polygon and rinkeby testnet
tried to re import the wallet on the imported account not linking properly and it says it's a duplicate so metamask is reading it  don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

ok found out the settings for allowance of metamask to read your internet were off and when allowing it to connect to all sites the balances appeared in the account again and were accurate.  still cannot log into the ox protocol which is scary cause that's where my coins are and commented on etherscan of pool activity but nothing back yet